# Add math to metrics in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5, kibana-6

I have this count metric:

[image]

Is it possible this number (457) multiply on some coefficient ?

For example 457 * (10 / 29) to get: 157,58

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, you need to use `Calculation` aggregation. Create a new `Visual Buidler` and select `Metric` at the top, choose count as the first aggregation and then click on plus button on the right in order to add another aggregation. As the second aggregation choose `Calculation`. Name your variable and from  expandable list pick `Count` next in the `Painless Script` field type in your desired formula `params.count  * 10 / 29`. That's how it should look like:

[image]